# Skull of corruption and the priest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to have the skull of corruption and the priest as a follower at the same time?

Comment: Without using the console?

Comment: Hey Draugr. One of the criteria for voting on questions is whether they show research effort. For Skyrim questions, this means you should check one or both of The Elder Scrolls Wiki or The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages before posting your question. If the answer is easily found on the first page related to your question, as it was here, you're probably going to get downvotes for lack of research.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is impossible normally.

The [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Nightmare) clearly states you have to get one or the other. I have also found no way of obtaining both during my plays. Quoted from the wiki:

> Here the choice is to kill Erandur as Vaermina commands and take the Skull of Corruption or let him complete his spell to destroy the Skull. If he lives, he can be a follower for no charge. However, this gives up the chance to acquire one of the Daedric artifacts, which are needed to obtain the Oblivion Walker achievement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. To get the Skull of Corruption you'd have to kill the priest and to keep the priest as a follower you'd have to destroy the skull.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lore friendly/imersive way to have both. But if you really want the skull (and if you are playing the pc version) open the console and type:

player.additem 35066 1

This will add the staff to your items. I would recomend doing it after completing the quest and getting the follower.